# Math determinant

Tags: math-mode

How to display this determinant:

[image: determinant display]

I have tried this:

```
\begin{vmatrix}
&a_{11}&&a_{12}&&a_{13}&\\
\\
&a_{21}&&a_{22}&&a_{23}&\\
\\
&a_{31}&&a_{32}&&a_{33}&\\
\end{vmatrix}
```

Comment: Welcome. Have you looked at Ti*k*Z or something similar?

Comment: Do you really think that Sarrus' rule is so useful? I beg to disagree. You find other methods for visualizing it at https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=sarrus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposal

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}
    \foreach \j in {1,2,3}
        \node (\i\j) at (\j,-\i) {$a_{\i\j}$};
\draw (11.north west)--(31.south west) (13.north east)--(33.south east);
\draw (11)--(22)--(33);
\begin{scope}[rounded corners]
    \draw (13)--(5,-3)--(3.5,-4.5)--(32)--(21);
    \draw (12)--(23)--(4,-3)--(2.5,-4.5)--(31);
\end{scope}
\draw[dashed] (13)--(22)--(31);
\begin{scope}[dashed,rounded corners]
    \draw (11)--(-1,-3)--(0.5,-4.5)--(32)--(23);
    \draw (12)--(21)--(0,-3)--(1.5,-4.5)--(33);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this displays with MathJax?

Comment: @Jerry No. Note that LaTeX is _not_ even a friend of MathJax - they are strangers.

Comment: Got that. Thanks!

Comment: Can you suggest a clean edit app of LaTex that could export as epub?

Comment: @Jerry I don't know. I only use LaTeX with its "default" output PDF. If necessary you should ask a new question.